# tail command does not display last line

Tags: linux, shell, tail, editors, text

I am using the following command to read the last line every time the  file changes.

```
tail -f -n1 Entrie.txt
```

It happens that the first line written shows it without problems, but later when I write the second it throws the following error

```
tail: Entrie.txt: file truncated
```

After showing that error, it shows all the values ​​written in the file. But it is not only that, after writing many lines the error stops coming out and is fixed, but I need it to always work well.

I am running this command in Linux.

I'm adding lines to the file in an editor and saving.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 2):

You can modify file by writing new version of it or appending data to current one.

Example in shell:

- `date > sample_file.txt` - recreates file with new text (output of `date` command)
- `date >> sample_file.txt` - appends text to current file

First case scenario - your file has been truncated (content deleted and recreated, it may be done with simple "write" in text editor) and `tail` warns about this. Second case - `tail` works as you intended.

Comment: Can't modify the txt from an editor?

Comment: @JuanFernandoNarvaez: No. Text editor (most of them) creates temporary file so you can edit it and do not mess with original content. When you are saving old file is truncated / deleted and substituted with temporary copy.

Comment: ok, your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When a text editor is saving a file, what very often happens is that it saves into a *temporary* file, empties (truncates) the original file, and copies the contents from the temporary file into the original file.  It does this to not alter the permissions, ownership and other meta-data on the original file.

This means that from the perspective of `tail`, the file is truncated (emptied), so it starts showing the last line of the file *as the editor is rewriting it* (which is why it displays the whole file).

To add lines to the file in such a way that your `tail` command always shows only the last line of the file and nothing else, you will have to make sure to *append* lines to the file.  Since text editors generally *rewrite* the file, you may have to do this using other means.

A very basic way of appending data to a file is by using `cat`:

```
cat >>Entrie.txt
```

This would make `cat` append to the file `Entrie.txt`.  It would wait for input from you, and you would be able to type directly into the file from the terminal.  The current line is written to the end of the file as soon as you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  To stop entering data, press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on an empty line.

This obviously does not give you any opportunity to correct what you have written on previous lines once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> though.

Another alternative would be to edit the new lines in a separate file, say `additions.txt`, with your editor.  Save that file and then do

```
cat additions.txt >>Entrie.txt
```

This would add the full contents of `additions.txt` to the end of the file `Entrie.txt`.